# identify if Instagram embed code is for photo or video

Tags: embed, instagram

Users of my website will enter Instagram embed codes. Do you know of an algorithmic way to identify if the Instagram embed code is for **photo** or **video**?

Comment: The embed code is the same for both videos and photos, you can parse the HTML of media permalink to check for original source (this can't be done via JS). Why would you need to do this anyway?

Comment: @AdamAzad *"Why would you need to do this anyway?"* Users of my website will be able to search for photos or videos. These photos and videos will be previously embedded via Instagram by other users. I want the results for a video search to only contain videos, and for a photo search to only contain photos. HTH.

Comment: You can add custom [HTML5 data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), then filter your results using them (I believe you're doing a live HTML search using JavaScript)

Comment: @AdamAzad that won't work because uniformly same embed boxes are presented to users, and users paste whatever embed codes they want, and then it's up to the site to segregate the embeds that were video from the embeds that were pics.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/4q77pzzb/) I created.

Comment: @AdamAzad It works! This is fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this API:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/{short-code}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and then get the data.type in response, it will have either "image" or "video"

Comment: Thanks (I haven't tried your solution yet, but @AdamAzad 's solution in the comments works!).